# How are <?php, ?>, and <html> tags inherited in include files?

Tags: php, include

(If there is a better way to word this question please do say so.)

Let's say I have a php file called example.php, that looks something like,

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
echo "hello world again";
?>
```

and I want to include another php file called part2.php that has some html and php like so,

```
<p>This is some html</p>
<?php
echo "and this is coming from php";
?>
<p>more html</p>
```

Do I need to end the php before I include the file, like so,

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
include("part2.php");
<?php
echo "hello world again.";
?>
```

or do I do make example.php like this,

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
include("part2.php");
echo "hello again world.";
?>
```

and then make part2.php like this,

```
?>
<p>This is some html</p>
<?php
echo "and this is coming from php";
?>
<p>more html</p>
<?php
```

or like this,

```
<p>This is some html</p>
<?php
echo "and this is coming from php";
?>
<p>more html</p>
```

Comment: Just read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, especially the blurb on example #2

Comment: you have identified a few possible cases. why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: you do realize that `?>
include("part2.php");
<?php` will throw a warning. Plus, nothing that hasn't already been covered on PHP.net and tutorial sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in PHP Docs about [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function:

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
>   mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
>   end. For this reason, **any code inside the target file which should be
>   executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end
>   tags.**

PHP parser will interpret code from `include` as if it's part of the original including file, which means your code will be treated as is was:

```
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
<p>This is some html</p>
<?php echo "and this is coming from php"; ?>
<p>more html</p>
<?php echo "hello again world."; ?>
```

Assuming, of course, that your `include("part2.php")` function is **properly enclosed** inside `<?php ?>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely have to do

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
include("part2.php");
echo "hello again world.";
?>
```

as otherwise the include would be outside the php tags and would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't over complicate it on yourself. Leave your example.php like this

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
include("part2.php");
echo "hello again world.";
?>
```

Then in your part2.php you can have it like this.

```
<p>This is some html</p>
<?php
echo "and this is coming from php";
?>
<p>more html</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP have to parse the include, so the php tags should be around.

example.php:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
include("part2.php");
echo "hello again world.";
?>
```

example2.php:

```
<p>This is some html</p>
<?php
echo "and this is coming from php";
?>
<p>more html</p>
```

You can include nearly erverything, so if you have php in your included file put the tags around it.
It is possible to include another file in your included file and so on...